# Why is Ajax4JSF Script automatically defined on top of HTML page?

Tags: jsf, ajax4jsf, jsf-1.1

I am using JSF 1.1 in a web application. When I run the app in IE 5 it has some UI problems. so, I used the meta tag to open the page in Edge compatibility.

Now I have used the Ajax4JSF tag library with URI - https://ajax4jsf.dev.java.net/ajax

The meta tag works only when its written above any other line in the head tag. The problem is that the Ajax4JSF library automatically declares a script in first line of the head tag.

It pushes my meta tag to second line causing the lose of Edge compatibility.

```
meta tag is - http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"

script declared is - /*appName*/a4j.res/org.ajax4jsf.framework.ajax.AjaxScript.jsf
```

How to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: u should include relevant info in your question rather than comments ! Just hit `edit` :D

Comment: So you are actually ajaxifying an application on a 15 year old standard for a 20 year old browser?